# Setting up webpack for angular2 to create bundles to files, instead of storing them in memory

Tags: iis, angular, webpack, windows-authentication

I am using Angular2 with Webpack that is set up according to [Angular2 webpack introduction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

When running the webpacks dev server it bundles my typescript files and loads them in the browser from memory.

Thing is, that I need to load the app from IIS, because it needs to have windows authentication, so I figured the only way develop would be to reconfigure webpack to create the bundled files on change instead of running a build command after each change.

How would I go about doing that?

My config files are identical to the ones from the tutorial [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#configure-webpack).

Also if I could still have livereload somehow, that would be great.

I will post the webpack.config files anyway.

webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out it's actually pretty simple. Instead of running the server with npm start just run webpack or webpack --watch, and add my desired output dir in the webpack.dev.js output section.

Can even remove the hashed name by removing [hash] field from naming templates everywhere, so don't need to update index.html at all.